# How to run tests and debug Google Test project in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, googletest

I want to run the sample tests and debug the [Google Test project](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest). I am using VS Code on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

- I cloned the project locally at `/home/user/Desktop/projects/cpp/googletest`,
- created a new directory called `mybuild` at `/home/user/Desktop/projects/cpp/mybuild`.
- According to the README instructions here: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest I used the command, `cmake -Dgtest_build_samples=ON /home/user/Desktop/projects/cpp/googletest` to build the project and this generated a bunch of files and apparently the build succeeded.

Now, I have 2 problems:

1. How do I run the sample tests for the project?
2. How do I debug these test and the source code for the project?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. Start with a clean directory:

```
/home/user/Desktop/projects/cpp/ # your project lives here
```

2. Add your cmake file(CMakeLists.txt), your source files, and test file. The directory now looks like this:

```
└─cpp/
    ├─ CMakeLists.txt
    ├─ myfunctions.h
    └─ mytests.cpp
```

3. Clone and add `googletest` to this directory:

```
└─cpp/
    ├─ googletest/
    ├─ CMakeLists.txt
    ├─ myfunctions.h
    └─ mytests.cpp
```

4. Open your `CMakeLists.txt` and enter the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12) # version can be different

project(my_cpp_project) #name of your project

enable_testing() #to  discover tests in test explorer 

add_subdirectory(googletest) # add googletest subdirectory

include_directories(googletest/include) # this is so we can #include <gtest/gtest.h>

add_executable(mytests mytests.cpp) # add this executable

target_link_libraries(mytests PRIVATE gtest) # link google test to this executable

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(mytests) # discovers tests by asking the compiled test executable to enumerate its tests
```

5. Contents of `myfunctions.h` for the example:

```
#ifndef _ADD_H
#define _ADD_H

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

#endif
```

6. Contents of `mytests.cpp` for the example:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "myfunctions.h"

TEST(myfunctions, add)
{
    GTEST_ASSERT_EQ(add(10, 22), 32);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Now you just have to run the tests. There are multiple ways to do that.

In the terminal, create a `build/` dir in `cpp/`:

```
mkdir build
```

Your directory should now look like this:

```
└─cpp/
    ├─ build/
    ├─ googletest/
    ├─ CMakeLists.txt
    ├─ myfunctions.h
    └─ mytests.cpp
```

Next go into the `build` directory:

```
cd build
```

Then run:

```
cmake ..
make
./mytests
```

Alternative way:

- Install the [`CMake Tools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extension for VS Code
- In the bottom bar, you can see the current target (in square brackets **Build [mytest]** and **Run [mytest]**)you want to build / run:
- Then just click the run button.

[image]

---

### Building Google test itself

#### Using terminal:

1. Go into the dir `/home/user/Desktop/projects/cpp/googletest`
2. Create `build/` inside it so that it looks like following:

```
└─cpp/googletest/
    ├─ build/
    ├─ ...other googletest files
```

3. `cd build`
4. Run: `cmake -Dgtest_build_samples=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`
5. `make -j4`
6. `./googletest/sample1_unittest`

#### Using VS-Code

1. Open the `googletest` folder into VS Code
2. CMake extension will prompt for configuration, allow it
3. You will see a `.vscode` directory. Inside it is `settings.json` file, open it, and add the following to it:

```
    "cmake.configureSettings": { "gtest_build_samples": "ON" }
```

4. Build and run from the buttons in the bottom bar

Comment: Thanks for answering but I think you misunderstood me. I dont have any project which I want to test using Google Test. I want to build and debug the Google Test library itself. Is it possible? How can I do it? PS: Please dont delete this answer, its quite good and will help me later when I use Google Test for writing tests for my project.

Comment: That should be even more simple, I will put it in the answer.

Comment: @Waqar When I try to Build I get **fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory**
I used **Using VS-Code** steps.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram are you able to build using the command line? And are you trying to build GoogleTest itself or do you want to write tests for your project?

Comment: @Waqar Yes, I built it as your answer suggested. Now I want to integrate it for a my own project where I will write test cases.
I cloned `googletest` and installed `CUnit` as VS-Code suggested way (Library)

Comment: If you want to integrate it into your project, you have to follow the instructions in the first part of the post(before **Building Google test itself**). The second part is if you want to build googletest and maybe contribute to the project.

Comment: @Waqar Do I have to use abuild system (i.e: Cmake) to be able to use Google test?

Comment: Not really. You can just use a makefile or nothing at all but you will need to adjust the include paths and link the gtest library correctly

Comment: If anyone facing the following error : ```/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```, just add `target_compile_options(gtest PRIVATE -fPIC)` before `target_link_libraries`. I have solved my issue in this way. I have to link the `gtest` with another library.

Comment: These explanations seem to imply that Google Test must be installed on each and every project where you wish to use it. Is this correct, or am I reading this wrong?