# Google Test + VSCode + WINDOWS, how can I use gtest in window OS?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, googletest

When I test cpp file on window vscode by using gtest and gmock,
I'm suffering from lots of errors..

So, I follow below guideline,
https://medium.com/swlh/google-test-installation-guide-for-c-in-windows-for-visual-studio-code-2b2e66352456

but **collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status** occured.

[image]

But gtest works well on visual studio!! But it does not work on vscode like above picture.

How can I handle this issue?
Also, I want to know how I can test cpp file in window vscode...

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910867/how-to-run-tests-and-debug-google-test-project-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run tests and debug Google Test project in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910867/how-to-run-tests-and-debug-google-test-project-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded `libgtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a` libraries that are not suitable to your compiler. Use Google tests from sources from the official Google test repository to build your own libraries https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/release-1.11.0

IMHO the guide you used demonstrates bad practice with coping libraries and header files to the compiler directories.