# How to i enable test suit for TDD for c++ in VS code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, tdd, googletest

I have visual studio code and I have gtest library installed as vcpkg.

when I run the test, it all works, but it will make my life easier if there is a test explorer UI for c++.

I have already installed c++ testmate extension, but I cant find the test buttons for individual tests.

I can do that with IDE's.

Comment: Have you gone through [How to use Google Test for C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: I have used that.

Comment: But i want to use the same thing on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I can install the Google Test library and make it work but I cant run the test suite independently but run all of them at once...

Comment: Maybe this question & answers will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62910867/4641116

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't see any unittesting each test suite. Just setting up Google test.